# 2-dim. pendulum: Which coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have a rather elementary question: I have a 2-dim pendulum and I do not know how I can descrive the coordinates.

In the 1-dim case one coordinates is enough_ the angle. But I do not know how it is here.

Comment: You can use spherical coordinates (angles): (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)

Comment: Then I need two angles and the distance?

Comment: You just need the 2 angles: the radius should be fixed since I suppose you are considering the length of the pendulum fixed.

Comment: Yes, the length is fixed but why do I need the two angles only? How can I write a point $(x,y,z)$ then?

Comment: If the origin is the pivot of your pendulum you just write: $x=L\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)$, $y=L\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$, $z=L\cos(\theta)$ where $L$ is the fixed length of the pendulum. As in the 1 dimensional case you just use polar coordinates where the radius is "replaced" by the fixed length of the pendulum.

Comment: You can also check: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_pendulum

Comment: What do you mean with: "If the origin is the pivot of your pendulum"?

Comment: When you use a coordinate system you are free to put the origin where you want: the convenient choice for your case is to put the origin at the point the string of your pendulum is fixed.

Comment: You should start with spherical coordinates. One important reason is your system has two symmetries. Translation symmetry in time and rotation symmetry along the $z$-axis. This leads to two constants of motion (the energy and angular momentum). If you work with spherical coordinates, you can use these two constants of motion to effectively turn your second degree ODE in two variables $(\theta,\phi)$ into a first degree ODE in one variable $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the equation of a circle is what you are after for a 2 dimensional plane.  Such as:
$$
(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2
$$
Where r is the radius. The x and y are the coordinates of a cartesian plane. a and b are the coordinates by which the center of the circle is translated from the origin.
Here is a web page on circles you may find useful.
http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/circle-equations.html